# Change the inner textbox 'mouse over' color of the MaterialDesign DatePicker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, textbox, material-design

Can i change DatePicker's TextBox underline and calender icon color?
like below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JukmD.png)

```
                                    <DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Start Date" Margin="0,25,0,0"
                                                materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="{StaticResource MainThemeColor3}">
                                        <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="Calendar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCalendarPortrait}">
                                                <Style.Resources>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="{StaticResource secondaryBackColor1}"/>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource secondaryBackColor2}"/>
                                                </Style.Resources>
                                            </Style>
                                        </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
                                    </DatePicker>
```

I tried like this but this can only change the color after clicked and focused one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dn9Y.png)

You can see that the icon's color still hasn't changed.

How can i change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `PrimaryHueMidBrush` for the `DatePicker` to change the colour of the icon:

```
<DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Start Date" Margin="0,25,0,0"
            materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="{StaticResource MainThemeColor3}">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Red" />
    </DatePicker.Resources>
    <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Calendar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCalendarPortrait}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="{StaticResource secondaryBackColor1}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource secondaryBackColor2}"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: Aha,

`<DatePicker.Resources> <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Red" /> </DatePicker.Resources>`

this override can simply change all of the colors :D:D

Thanks!! Helped a lot :D:D